# Calibrating the R&S FPL 1003 Spectrum Analyzer

Tags: emc, high-frequency, function-generator, calibration, spectrum-analyzer

I am setting up an EMC test bench and I have a spectrum analyzer(SA): The Rohde and Schwarz FPL 1003 Spectrum Analyzer. I am trying to conduct some preliminary tests to ensure that the results seen on the analyzer are correct.

For this I gave a sine wave of a particular frequency(100kHz) and magnitude(2V p-p) from a function generator to the SA and monitored the output.

The output:
Fundamental (100kHz) and it's multiple frequencies match on the spectrum seen on SA. However, the magnitude seen is quite different.

Now, the function generator has 3 options for 'load setting': 1. 50Ohm 2. High Z and 3. Load

In High Z setting:
i/p : 2Vp-p i.e. 0 to 1 Vpk || o/p (on SA) : 353mV

In 50Ohm setting:
i/p: same || o/p(on SA) : 671mV

In Load setting:
i/p: same || o/p(on SA) : 671mV

Is there anything that I am missing here to not get the exact 1V output in spectrum analyzer?

Comment: Not clear if the 671 mV reading is RMS or peak. Most analyzers will display in VRMS, unless changed by the user. If the reading is VRMS, 1 VPK = 0.707 VRMS and the error in dB is 20*log(671mV/707mV)=-0.5 dB, which is very likely within the SA's spec, and this is neglecting any error contributed by the signal generator.

Comment: @Just_visiting but what about the load setting? Does the SA offer 50Ohm load?

Comment: Yes, almost all RF SAs have a fixed 50-Ohm input and it is usually indicated on the front panel over the input connector.

Comment: Yes, it does have that indication on the front panel. Then, in that case, the load setting in the function generator should also be 50Ohm, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be best.

Comment: @Just_visiting Is there a way to know for sure that the measurement that I'm seeing on the SA is actually correct?

Comment: You could check it with another piece of equipment, like an oscilloscope measuring the voltage from your signal generator driving a 50-Ohm resistor/load. Or, use a "T" connector to simultaneously drive the SA and scope (with a hi-Z input) and compare the readings.

Comment: Okay, will do that. One more thing I observed is that there is an option in the SA to change the attenuation. However, after I changed it to various levels, the magnitude of the peak observed was not changed. Shouldn't the attenuation affect the magnitude as well?

Comment: If the attenuation is inserted by the SA internally, it's smart enough to know it's there and adjusts the displayed level to reflect the actual value at the input connector.

Comment: Rohde & Schwarz $10000,- equipment is a little more than most of us can afford. I have seen such tools in use only in places where the budget covers professional calibration once in the year for every electronic measurement instrument used in the production. You should be one of them if you are going to use your tools in doing something seriously. Tools in this league should have a quick check reference signal source - for ex. a 100 MHz pulse source with known spectrum and power.